# how to display wordpress navbar with top menu outside wordpress system

Tags: menus, customization

i want to display my wordpress top navbar outside of wordpress system in one of my php site, so that whenever i change the wordpress navbar the changes will reflect on my php site.

How to do that?

I have found it somewhere but unable to know how to use it:

```
// no theme output
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

// initializes the entire Wordpress
require '/path/to/your/wp/wp-blog-header.php';

// here you print your menu
wp_nav_menu('your_theme_menu_location');
```

Comment: Hi Manindra Singh, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Comment: @kraftner: i have read it somewhere but unable to knwo that where and how to put this code.you can check my updated question.